# sed to replace blanks with newlines in OS X

Tags: regex, bash, sed, osx-yosemite

I want to replace blanks with newline characters in a file. Bunch of other things I tried from the answers to other questions here didn't work:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' file 
sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]\+/\n/g' file
```

These both return the file as it is. I tried the following:

```
sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]/\n/g' file
```

which replaces the blanks with `n`s.

I assume the difference is due to the difference between `gnu` `sed` and the one in OS X. How can I achieve this in OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to insert a new line (actually a new line).

```
$ echo 'this will replace blanks with new lines' | sed 's/ /\
/g'
```

Comment: I think he wants to compress all the consecutive spaces into a single newline.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` on OS X doesn't recognize `\n` in the replacement, you need to use a literal newline, and you have to escape it to prevent it from ending the command. It also doesn't understand the `\s` or `+`, so use `[[:blank:]]\{1,}` to match one or more spaces.

```
sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/\
/g' file
```

Comment: You can use some extended regular expression syntax, as `+`, with `-E` option of BSD sed

Comment: I tried it on OS X, it didn't work. I'm on Snow Leopard, not Yosemite, but I'll bet they haven't changed `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

The `tr` command is easier/more-suitable IMO:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < $FILE_PATH
```

or:

```
echo 'this will replace blanks with new lines' | tr ' ' '\n'
```